# travelling to us with 10 years visa and being asked to carry hospital bills of my us born kids

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I just got my 10 years US visa and planning to travel next July 2019. I have been asked during the interview to carry the hospital bills of the two kids born in the US 15 years ago. What are the possibilities of being denied entry?

Comment: Did you pay the bills? Do you have evidence of having done so?

Comment: Are you carrying them to try and prove they should get entry into the US, or for another reason?

Comment: Are you traveling with your kids? Do they have US passports? (If not, why not?)

Comment: Nobody can tell you the probability of being denied entry however is it possible to be denied entry? **YES** and for any of a number of reasons. With respect to carrying along the hospital bills, it is **likely** because they might want to verify if you made use of public resources in your pregnancy and delivery. If you did then there is a high probability of being denied entry. A simple google search will confirm that visitors are being denied entry and visas revoked for taking advantage of public resources in the USA

Comment: yes my kids are travelling with me (they are both citizen) and my wife has a 10 years visa. been 15 years now and I lost hospital bill. during the interview when I got my visa approved they told me to take bills with me when travelling ( as I didn't have them when I went for interview)